# Matplotlib x axis plotted out of order

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm running the python script below and the x axis should be

20  10 5

but it's plotted

5 10 20

they aren't strings and I don't know what's sorting this. Math is NOT my gig so all I'm trying to do is find the regression line between the data points. I'm concerned that having the x axis out of order will give me poor results. Any ideas please.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [ 20,10,5 ] 
y = [ 30,35,40 ]

x_new = 100
y_new = np.interp(x_new, x, y)

print(y_new)

plt.plot(x, y, "og-");

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few orderings here which are conceptually separate: "the order of the data", "the order in which the points are plotted", and "the direction of the axis".  The direction of the axis is not set by the order of the data, although the data is plotted in the order of the data.

It's helpful here to consider what's done with x data that both goes up and down (ie, is non-monotonic).  It wouldn't make sense here to have the x-axis be non-monotonic, instead, matplotlib makes a normal axis, but plots the points in the order they are defined in the data.

```
x = [ 20,10,5 ] 
y = [ 30,35,40 ]
plt.plot(x, y, "og-")

x2 = [ 20, 0, 10, 5 ] 
y2 = [ 30, 0, 35, 40 ]
plt.plot(x2, y2, "or-")
```

[image: 0,]

Comment: Hi Tom  I'm not skilled at math so this is my first attempt at linear regression so please bear with me. As an example the x = days so x = 20 is 20 days 10 = 10 days , so on period 20 the value measured was 30 then 10 days y = 35 so the line would slope UP.  The order is important isn't it?  20 10 5 days.

Comment: @theakson: "important" is a bit subjective, but YES, the order may absolutely be important. What I want you to be clear about with my answer is that there are several "orders" going on. The order of the data (and the interpolation since you feed the data directly into it), and then the order in the plotting of that data. These should be thought of as separate questions, and are almost entirely independent.  The order is important in both: for the data it’s doing the calculation correctly, and for plotting it’s doing things so that you and others can understand it correctly.

Comment: @theakson: As for whether to flip the x-axis, it depends on the data and "days" doesn't define what it should be. Overall, flipping the axis is an unusual thing, and since you’re not experienced, I would give it extra thought to make sure it’s the right thing. Since you say “days”: Time axes should (almost) always have past on the left and future on the right, so if the axis is "days in the past" then 30 should be to the left of 20; but here you should instead deal with this by defining it as -30 and -20, so -30 is "30 days ago", and is naturally represented in an axis that is not flipped.

Comment: Ok so I am REALLY going to dig into this now. You explanation was EXCELLENT and thank you for taking the time. I'm going to hit the books and figure out what I am trying to do here AND how to do it effectively. I understand completely what you are trying to say and sorry to be so "dull" my only excuse is that I dozed through stats and math... thanks again

Comment: @theakson: I'm glad it was helpful. Since you're starting out, I'd suggest that plotting the data is a helpful way to see what's going on, but if the plotting is complicating things, you can also just use a very minimal data set (like the 3 pairs you show) and make sure the numbers of the regression make sense to you (especially the signs, ie, + or -, of everything for your case, and they can be a bit easy to overloook -- in science/math we talk about "sign errors" for this reason). Change the numbers and/or their order and make sure it still makes sense. Then work on the plotting.

Comment: It was VERY helpful. I'm having to go back to first principals and work through this. The numbers are percentages taken at 20 days 10 days and 5 days which represent the historical volatility of a stock price.  I wanted to see if I could arrive at a single relationship that represents the change between 20 10 and 5 days. I thought that a regression analysis might be the way to go. The numbers can't be -ve as it's historical vol. thanks again for such a wonderful answer and guidance

Answer (score 2):

Pyplot by default has standard axis direction. Since you are plotting numerical values, the axis will be increasing from left to right. You can, for example, follow [this sample](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/invert_axes.html) to invert the axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, "og-");
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(xmax, xmin)
plt.show()
```

Or you can also use `ax.invert_xaxis()`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, "og-");

ax.invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, this was spot on and really helped me out.